# AttributeError: 'class1' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x

A lame question regarding Classes:

```
class class1:

  def __init__(self):
    self = []

  def insert1(self,x):
    self.append(x) /// the object is a list in which x to be appended

a = class1()
a.insert1(5)
```

And I get: AttributeError: 'class1' object has no attribute 'append'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just assign a list to `self`; all you did was *rebind* the local name to a list object.

You'll either have to subclass the `list` type:

```
class class1(list):
    def insert1(self, x):
        self.append(x)
```

or assign a new list object to an attribute on `self`:

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self._lst = []

    def insert1(self, x):
        self._lst.append(x)
```